# What happen at the `continue` after a async has yielded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, yield

The `continue` statement in the following snippet suspends the `while` loop once the condition has met. Would someone help me understand what is going under the hood? Thanks!

```
import asyncio

async def yield_even():
    count = 0
    while True:
        if count % 2 != 0:
            continue

        yield count

        if count > 5:
            break

        count += 1


async def main():
    async for i in yield_even():
        print(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

You got infinite loop there, because you do not increment your `count` in that case and once this particular condition is met, it's met forever as no code pass that `if` will ever be executed.

Also there no point fir `while True` loop if you have counter based iteration limit. Do regular `for`